# How to extract time class from HTML in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I have a piece of HTML code in python through beautifulsoup but am unable to retrieve the desired time tag from it.

```
HTML is called K:

<time class="dtstart" datetime="05 December 201710:30 AM GMT" id="x-event-date" xcdate="1512469800950">
<a class="action pull-right print-cat" data-href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html" data-modalid="catalogueModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/en/auctions/ecatalogue/lot.print.L17407.html" style="display: none;">Print My Catalogue (0)</a>
<ul class="breadcrumb inline">
<li>
<a href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html"><span class="active">Smartphone and watches</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</time>
```

I can extract all tags except time:

```
K.a :
<a class="action pull-right print-cat" data-href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html" data-modalid="catalogueModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/en/auctions/ecatalogue/lot.print.L17407.html" style="display: none;">Print My Catalogue (0)</a>

K.li:
<li>
<a href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html"><span class="active">Smartphone and watches</span></a>
</li>

K.time:
Nothing prints
```

I have also tried the following solution:

```
K.find('time', {'class':'dtstart'})
Nothing prints

K.find('a', {'class':'action pull-right print-cat'})
<a class="action pull-right print-cat" data-href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html" data-modalid="catalogueModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/en/auctions/ecatalogue/lot.print.L17407.html" style="display: none;">Print My Catalogue (0)</a>
```

When we inspect K we see the following:

```
Signature:      K(*args, **kwargs)
Type:           Tag
String form:   
<time class="dtstart" datetime="05 December 201710:30 AM GMT" id="x-event-date" xcdate="1512469800950">
<a class="action pull-right print-cat" data-href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html" data-modalid="catalogueModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/en/auctions/ecatalogue/lot.print.L17407.html" style="display: none;">Print My Catalogue (0)</a>
<ul class="breadcrumb inline">
<li>
<a href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html"><span class="active">Smartphone and watches</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</time>  
Length:         5
File:           ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py
Source:
```

How is it possible the time tag isn't being extracted?

Comment: What is the source url and expected output value? Have you confirmed it is not dynamically loaded? Seems likely the webpage is making an additional xhr for this or is using js to calculate/populate from elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure why I am not able to receive it in the first place, but Chris Doyle paved the way to succes. We can simply resoup it and get the desired result:

```
Date=soup(str(K), "html.parser").time.attrs["datetime"]
print(Date)

#Output
{'class': ['dtstart'], 'datetime': '05 December 201710:30 AM GMT', 'id': 'x-event-date', 'xcdate': '1512469800950'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double check the html code your receiving in your script. using a minimal example with the html in your question, its clear that bs4 can get a time tag.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = """<time class="dtstart" datetime="05 December 201710:30 AM GMT" id="x-event-date" xcdate="1512469800950">
<a class="action pull-right print-cat" data-href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html" data-modalid="catalogueModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/en/auctions/ecatalogue/lot.print.L17407.html" style="display: none;">Print My Catalogue (0)</a>
<ul class="breadcrumb inline">
<li>
<a href="/en/aus/2017/some-url-data-l17407.html"><span class="active">Smartphone and watches</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</time>"""

k = BeautifulSoup(html_string, features="lxml")
print(k.time.attrs)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'class': ['dtstart'], 'datetime': '05 December 201710:30 AM GMT', 'id': 'x-event-date', 'xcdate': '1512469800950'}
```